# Как десериализовать json

Tags: c#, json

Есть следующий json

```
[{
    "id": [
      "11412424829"
    ],
    "o": [
      366
    ],
    "g": 3,
    "l": [
      "14720829159177850865"
    ],
    "c": 1,
    "m": "StatTrak™ AK-47 | Fire Serpent",
    "z": 4,
    "e": "FN",
    "u": "cm9",
    "p": 4271.25,
    "f": [
      "0.06850684"
    ],
    "y": [
      4
    ],
    "n": [
      0
    ],
    "b": [
      "76561198316800514"
    ],
    "v": 9,
    "h": 6
  },
  {
    "id": [
      "11412545230"
    ],
    "o": [
      650
    ],
    "g": 2,
    "l": [
      "9803423996325074679"
    ],
    "m": "★ Karambit | Gamma Doppler Emerald",
    "z": 4,
    "e": "FN",
    "u": "ddb",
    "p": 4162.1,
    "f": [
      "0.02687659"
    ],
    "y": [
      8
    ],
    "n": [
      "@TranceM8"
    ],
    "b": [
      "76561198338195694"
    ],
    "h": 6
  }
  ]
```

Пытаюсь его перевести в класс. Сгенерировал через встроенный генератор.

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public Class1[] Property1 { get; set; }
}

public class Class1
{
    public string[] id { get; set; }
    public int[] o { get; set; }
    public int g { get; set; }
    public string[] l { get; set; }
    public int c { get; set; }
    public string m { get; set; }
    public int z { get; set; }
    public string e { get; set; }
    public string u { get; set; }
    public float p { get; set; }
    public string[] f { get; set; }
    public int[] y { get; set; }
    public object[] n { get; set; }
    public string[] b { get; set; }
    public int v { get; set; }
    public int h { get; set; }
}
```

Вот итоговый код.

```
JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var json = File.ReadAllText("1.txt");
var rez = js.Deserialize<Rootobject[]>(json);
```

Почему элементы  `Property1` пустые, хотя сериализация не вызвала ошибко.

Comment: Нужно просто `Deserialize<Rootobject>` - без квадратных скобок. Потому что массив внутри этого объекта.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас `JSON` имеет структуру массива данных, без какого либо имени. На сколько я знаю - указав `public Class1[] Property1 { get; set; }` ожидается что то вроде `"Property1": []`, а уж внутри ваш объект. В вашем случае это простой массив, который содержит в себе уже `Class1`.

Решение простое, укажите в строке `var rez = js.Deserialize<Rootobject[]>(json);` не `Rootobject[]`, а `Class1[]`.

Кстати, для таких целей существует отличный [сайт](http://json2csharp.com/), который конвертирует `JSON` в класс, попробуйте через него прогнать ваши данные и посмотрите на результат.